# How to import index with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have a model named Article in my Rails 3, and I use `rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article' FORCE=true` to do index. But I only want the articles with field `deleted` equals to false be indexed. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scoped method.

```
rake environment tire:import CLASS='Article.scoped(:conditions => {:deleted => false})' FORCE=true
```

Reference: Answered by [karmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95696/karmi) @ https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/458

Answer (score 1):

[Above Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452877/how-to-import-index-with-condition/14481118#14481118) doesn't seem to work.

What ever we pass to `CLASS` environment variable is only used to find tire index and calculate `total` for progress bar. Check `Line 97: total  = klass.count rescue nil` and `Line 49: klass.tire.import(params) do |documents|` from https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/master/lib/tire/tasks.rb

Only working solution I found (with mongoid) is,

```
Tire.index "articles" do
   import Article.scoped(:conditions => {:deleted => false}) 
end
```

Which is as good as saying `Article.index.import( Article.scoped(:conditions => {:deleted => false}))` as answered by karmi @ https://github.com/karmi/tire/issues/458

But advantage of using above approach is when we need custom mappings. like below

```
Tire.index "articles" do
   import Article.scoped(:conditions => {:deleted => false}) do|documents|
     documents.map{|document| document[:content].downcase!; document}
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me in the latest Tire gem.  It did work in Tire v0.5.4 but not in v0.6.2.  So, to create a rake task, I did this...

```
desc 'Index articles'
task :index => :environment do
  Article.where(:deleted => false).find_in_batches do |batch|
    Tire.index(Article.index_name).import batch
  end
end
```

Using find_in_batches was recommended on the [readme](https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/master/README.markdown#activemodel-integration).